# Cloning a class in es6

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

es6 newbie here,

I'm trying to create a class that has another class as its property.

My problem is that I'm unable to 'clone' the class for its property.

As you see below, my intention is to use the `Component.getAll()` static method to only return the items created inside the `MyClass` instance.

I've tried searching around for a few things, 'mixins' came up, but I don't believe that would solve my problem.

```js
'use strict'
class Component {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
    Component.addItem(this)
  }

  static addItem(item) {
    if (!this._items) {
      this._items = []
    }
    this._items.push(item)
  }

  static getAll() {
    return this._items
  }

  static getById(id) {
    return this._items.find(i => i.id === id)
  }
}


class MyClass {
  constructor(things) {

    //This is where my issue is.
    this.Component = Component


    things.forEach(t => new Component(t))
  }
}

function showIds(divId, items) {
  let ids = items.map(i => i.id)
  document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = ids.toString()
}

let a = new MyClass([1, 2, 3])
a.Component.getById(1) //-> returns what is expected
let aItems = a.Component.getAll() // -> [1,2,3]
showIds('a', aItems)

//I would like b.Component.getAll() to only output -> [4,5,6]
//But because i can;t 'clone' the class, Its just adding the items into the same bucket. 
let b = new MyClass([4, 5, 6])
b.Component.getById(1) //-> should return undefined
let bItems = b.Component.getAll() // -> [1,2,3,4,5,6]
showIds('b', bItems)
```

```html
<div id="a">
</div>

<div id="b">
</div>
```

Declaring the `Component` class INSIDE `MyClass` seems to do the trick... But it feels like it could get messy when using `require` or `import`

```js
'use strict'



class MyClass {
  constructor(things) {

    class Component {
      constructor(id) {
        this.id = id
        Component.addItem(this)
      }

      static addItem(item) {
        if (!this._items) {
          this._items = []
        }
        this._items.push(item)
      }

      static getAll() {
        return this._items
      }

      static getById(id) {
        return this._items.find(i => i.id === id)
      }
    }

    this.Component = Component


    things.forEach(t => new Component(t))
  }
}

function showIds(divId, items) {
  let ids = items.map(i => i.id)
  document.getElementById(divId).innerHTML = ids.toString()
}

let a = new MyClass([1, 2, 3])
let aItems = a.Component.getAll() // -> [1,2,3]
showIds('a', aItems)

 
let b = new MyClass([4, 5, 6])
let bItems = b.Component.getAll() // -> [4,5,6]
showIds('b', bItems)
```

```html
<div id="a">
</div>

<div id="b">
</div>
```

I'd be grateful for any suggestions!

Comment: A static collection of all instances is a very very bad idea, as you are effectively preventing garbage collection of all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static methods are designed to be single for each class. If you want them not to be single, you probably don't need static methods.

You can add an extra class named `ComponentsCollection`, that does `Component` tracking for you. Let's move there all static methods from `Component`

```
class Component {
  constructor(id) {
    this.id = id
  }
}


class ComponentsCollection {
  constructor() {
    this._components = [];
  }

  createComponent(id) {
     const component = new Component(id);
     this.components.push(component);
     return component;
  }

  getAll() {
    return this._components;
  }
}
```

Then you can instantiate `ComponentsCollection` in `MyClass` and use it to create Components

```
class MyClass {
  constructor(things) {
    this.collection = new ComponentsCollection();

    things.forEach(t => this.collection.createComponent(t));
  }
}
```

Check this out:

```
let a = new MyClass([1, 2, 3])
console.log(a.collection.getAll().map(i => i.id))  // [1,2,3]
let b = new MyClass([4, 5, 6])
console.log(b.collection.getAll().map(i => i.id))  // [4,5,6]
```

Comment: Brilliant. Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for, a 'collection manager class'.

Answer (score 1):

> As you see below, my intention is to use the `Component.getAll()` static method to only return the items created inside the `MyClass` instance.

The issue is that there is only a single `Component` class and a single `Component._items` property (and value). Every instance of `MyClass` (indirectly) access *the same* `Component._items` value.

> Declaring the Component class INSIDE MyClass seems to do the trick...

Yes, because now every instance has it's own `Component` class.

> But it feels like it could get messy when using `require` or `import`

I don't see how.

However, I do agree that creating a class inside the another class' constructor seems to be odd. Maybe keeping track of the `Component` instances should not be part of `Component` itself but be part of `MyClass`.

Whatever the solution you choose, every instance must have it's own array where it keeps track of its `Component` instances.

Comment: Discard the "maybe".